# Bash script to find the specific files in the folder and show the sizes

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have an array of file names like below, I want to find and learn the sizes in the folder. I wrote the bash script below but it is finding all the files in the folder recursively.

```
files=( a/ddd/dd ddd/b dfgf/fgdfg/c dfgdfg/dfgdfg/d dsf/e rret/ertert/erter/f)

for u in "${files[@]}"  
do  
    find . "[^\/]+$" $u".js" -exec du -sh {} \;
done
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to clarify what you are trying to do? Is `dfgf/fgdfg/c.js` a file whose size you want to know, or is `dfgf/fgdfg/c` a *directory* that contains `*.js` files whose size you want to know?

Answer (score 1):

From `man find`

```
-maxdepth levels
          Descend  at  most  levels  (a  non-negative  integer)  levels  of directories below the starting-points.
          -maxdepth 0
           means only apply the tests and actions to the starting-points themselves.
```

Try

```
find . -maxdepth 0 -name "[^\/]+$" $u".js" -exec du -sh {} \;
```

I rarely use find with -exec (because I always forget about it) so I apologize if this is wrong

Comment: Please finish your answer by including the entire `find` command. Even though the question is unclear, you can re-edit your answer if the question is edited.

Comment: The `-exec` part look fine to me, but I'm having a hard time understanding what `-name "[^\/]+$" $u".js"` is intended to do here. AFAIK `-name` takes a *single* simple shell glob (not a regex) as argument, and matches against only the filename portion (so a `-name` pattern can't contain slashes)

Comment: it might be the I interpreted the man page wrong :/  `The metacharacters (``*', ``?', and ``[]') match a ``.' at the start of  the  base  name`